# Object rendering to Json - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently working on an SDK for integrating with an API (as Client). My problem is (I am not even sure this is a problem), but I wanted my request to only contain the parameters that are initialized. Example of how they are being generated now:

```
{
   "scenarioKey":"",
   "bulkId":"",
   "destinations":[
      {
         "messageId":"xxxxx",
         "to":{
            "phoneNumber":""
         }
      }
   ],
   "sms":null
}
```

The SMS parameter was never initiated hence I wanted it not to be included in the request body, is that a way I can have a request without this parameter "**sms**"?

By the way I am using HttpEntity:

```
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyObject, headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot allows simple configuration of the Jackson ObjectMapper it uses in the application.properties file.

The supported properties are described in the documentation. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Specifically `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` in the application.properties should do the trick.

If you want to do this for specific classes or attributes Jackson has the annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information mate! I resolved it super quick with your tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jackson to serialize your JSON, you should take a look at the `setSerializationInclusion()` method on `ObjectMapper` https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setSerializationInclusion(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include)

Here is a simple testcase that prevents the `sms` field from being included in the JSON output:

```
@Test
public void testJson() throws Exception {
    Addr addr = new Addr();
    addr.phoneNumber = "";
    Destination destination = new Destination();
    destination.messageId = "";
    destination.to = addr;
    Scenario scenario = new Scenario();
    scenario.scenarioKey = "";
    scenario.bulkId = "";
    scenario.destinations = Arrays.asList(destination);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(scenario));
}

public static class Scenario {
    public String scenarioKey;
    public String bulkId;
    public List<Destination> destinations;
    public String sms;
}
public static class Destination {
    public String messageId;
    public Addr to;
}
public static class Addr {
    public String phoneNumber;
}
```